# Is there a reason why DataInputStream.read() only reads the first few bytes of really big arrays (>100,000 bytes)?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, io, datainputstream

I'm trying to write software that sends a set of data (a portion of a video game) in different formats (chunked, compressed, raw), and measures the speed between each. However, I'm running into an issue while sorting out the CHUNKED method. I've found that, when reading byte array sizes of more than 140000 bytes, the client starts to only read up to around 131072, no matter how much bigger the array actually is. Is there a reason for this, or potentially a better way to do this? My code is shown below. I'm using the [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)) method of DataInputStream (and its return value).

**SERVER**

```
/**
 *
 * @return Time taken to complete transfer.
 */
public int start(String mode, int length) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if(mode.equals("RAW")){
        byte[] all = new ByteCollector(ServerMain.FILES, length).collect();
        output.writeUTF("SENDING " + mode + " " + all.length);
        expect("RECEIVING " + mode);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        echoSend(all);
        return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }else if(mode.equals("CHUNKED")){ /*the important part*/
        //split into chunks
        byte[] all = new ByteCollector(ServerMain.FILES, length).collect();
        int chunks = maxChunks(all);
        output.writeUTF("SENDING " + mode + " " + chunks);
        System.out.println("Expecting RECEIVING " + chunks + "...");
        expect("RECEIVING " + chunks);
        int ms = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<chunks; i++){
            byte[] currentChunk = getChunk(i, all);
            System.out.println("My chunk length is " + currentChunk.length);
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Sending...");
            echoSend(currentChunk);
            ms += System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        }
        if(chunks == 0) expect("0"); //still need to confirm, even though no data was sent
        return ms;
    }else if(mode.equals("COMPRESSED")){
        byte[] compressed = new ByteCollector(ServerMain.FILES, length).collect();
        compressed = ExperimentUtils.compress(compressed);
        output.writeUTF("SENDING " + mode + " " + compressed.length);
        expect("RECEIVING " + mode);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        echoSend(compressed, length);
        return (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
    FILES = Files.walk(Paths.get(DIRECTORY)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).toArray(Path[]::new);
    SyncServer server = new SyncServer(new ServerSocket(12222).accept());
    System.out.println("--------[CH UNK ED]--------");
    short[] chunkedSpeeds = new short[FOLDER_SIZE_MB + 1/*for "zero" or origin*/];
    for(int i = 0; i<=FOLDER_SIZE_MB; i++){
        chunkedSpeeds[i] = (short) server.start("CHUNKED", i * MB);
        System.out.println(i + "MB, Chunked: " + chunkedSpeeds[i]);
    }
    short[] compressedSpeeds = new short[FOLDER_SIZE_MB + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=FOLDER_SIZE_MB; i++){
        compressedSpeeds[i] = (short) server.start("COMPRESSED", i * MB);
    }
    short[] rawSpeeds = new short[FOLDER_SIZE_MB + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i<=FOLDER_SIZE_MB; i++){
        rawSpeeds[i] = (short) server.start("RAW", i * MB);
    }
    System.out.println("Raw speeds: " + Arrays.toString(rawSpeeds));
    System.out.println("\n\nCompressed speeds: " + Arrays.toString(compressedSpeeds));
    System.out.println("\n\nChunked speeds: " + Arrays.toString(chunkedSpeeds));
}
```

**CLIENT**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 12222);
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    while(socket.isConnected()){
        String response = input.readUTF();
        String[] content = response.split(" ");
        if(response.startsWith("SENDING CHUNKED")){
            int chunks = Integer.parseInt(content[2]);
            System.out.println("Read chunk amount of " + chunks);
            output.writeUTF("RECEIVING " + chunks);
            for(int i = 0; i<chunks; i++){
                byte[] chunk = new byte[32 * MB];
                System.out.println("Ready to receive...");
                int read = input.read(chunk);
                System.out.println("Echoing read length of " + read);
                output.writeUTF(String.valueOf(read));
            }
            if(chunks == 0) output.writeUTF("0");
        }else if(response.startsWith("SENDING COMPRESSED")){
            byte[] compressed = new byte[Integer.parseInt(content[2])];
            output.writeUTF("RECEIVING " + compressed.length);
            input.read(compressed);
            decompress(compressed);
            output.writeInt(decompress(compressed).length);
        }else if(response.startsWith("SENDING RAW")){
            int length = Integer.parseInt(content[2]);
            output.writeUTF("RECEIVING " + length);
            byte[] received = new byte[length];
            input.read(received);
            output.writeInt(received.length);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public static byte[] decompress(byte[] in) throws IOException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InflaterOutputStream infl = new InflaterOutputStream(out);
        infl.write(in);
        infl.flush();
        infl.close();

        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error decompressing byte array with length " + in.length);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Using SDK 17

I tried switching around the byte amount, and found the cutoff was right where I stated above. I even replicated this in a test client/server project with no frills (find that [here](https://pastebin.com/qcjJKhy8), and found that the cutoff was even lower! I really hope this isn't an actual issue with Java...

Comment: If this is TCP, do you understand that there's no correlation between the number of bytes in a single send, and the number of bytes delivered to a single recv?  At the socket level, a read completes when there are 'some' bytes to read.

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen? The `read()` method is working the way it is supposed to, the way the documentation says it should work. Maybe you want [`readFully()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully(byte%5B%5D))?

Comment: In general, you just need to read in a loop until you've read everything.  How do you know when that is?  You need a protocol that tells you; typically either there's a length (as in the Content-Length header of HTTP) or else you read until the end of the connection.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! It seems I've misunderstood some fundamentals. I assumed Java's APIs had some magical way of knowing how many bytes were sent in one go. At least my question will help some other dude whose wracking his brain over the same thing...

Answer (score 1):

The read() method of DataInputStream doesn't directly correspond to the write() method of DataOutputStream. If you want to know how many bytes were sent in a single method call, the server has to inform the client manually.

This is because the read() method, since it doesn't depend on a set length, treats its process as completed when *some* bytes are read, as it has no way of knowing how many you want.